# Redirect to same ajax page after reload or form submission with old input data

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a dashboard with some side menus. Each menus loads a page through ajax call after it is clicked. 
By default when dashboard is loaded it loads the page, there is also a "dashboard" menu to switch between others like profile and add student.

**But if I am at profile page and I refresh It goes back to dashboard page. Also if I try to add student by filling the form and if the form has any error it goes back to dashboard again with all old input data lost.**

**Web.php**

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
Route::get('/dashboard','AdminController@dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
Route::post('/add_student','AdminController@add_student');

    Route::middleware('ajax')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/summary','AdminController@summary')->name('admin.summary');
    Route::get('/profile', 'AdminController@profile')->name('admin.profile');
    Route::get('/add_student_form','AdminController@add_student_form')->name('admin.add_student');
});

});
```

**AdminController.php**

```
 public function add_student_form(){
    return view('admin.add_student');
}

public function add_student(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[

        'name'=>'required|string',
        'course_id'=>'required',
        'dob'=>'required|date',
        'gender'=>'required|string',
        'category'=>'required|string',
        'qualification'=>'required|string',
        'fathername'=>'required|string',
        'mothername'=>'required|string',
        'mob_no'=>'required|string|max:10',
        'address'=>'required|string',
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'PIN'=>'required|string|max:6',
    ]);

    $student = new Student;
    $student->name = $request['name'];
    $student->roll_no ='NITTI'.rand(10000,99999);
    $student->password = Hash::make($student['mob']);

    $student->fees = new StudentFees;
    $student->fees->paid_fees = $request['paid_fees'];
    $student->fees->balance_fees = 7000;
    $student->detail = new StudentDetail;
    $student->detail->course_id = $request['course_id'];
    $student->detail->gender = $request['gender'];
    $student->detail->category = $request['category'];
    $student->detail->qualification = $request['qualification'];
    $student->detail->fathername = $request['fathername'];
    $student->detail->mothername = $request['mothername'];
    $student->detail->mob_no = $request['mob_no'];
    $student->detail->email = $request['email'] ;
    $student->detail->address = $request['address'];
    $student->detail->PIN=$request['PIN'];
    $student->detail->dob = $request['dob'];
    $student->push();
    return redirect()->back();

}
```

**add_student.blade.php**

```
  <form action="/admin/add_student" method="POST">
      @csrf
   //It has all the fields here and a submit button
   </form>
```

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-2  sidebar">
            <img src="{{asset('/img/admin.jpg')}}" class="fit-image">
             <p class="text-center">{{Auth::user()->name}}</p>
             <hr>

         <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" id="summary">Dashboard</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="admin_profile">Profile
            </li> 
            <li class="list-group-item" id="students">Students <i class="fas fa-angle-right ml-5"></i>
           <ul class="sidenav list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" id="add_student">Add Student</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="viewall">View All </li>
          </ul></li> 
        </ul>
       </div>
         <div class="col-10 dashboard" id="admin">
         </div>
        </div>
         </div>
```

**dashboard.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url:'/admin/summary',
          type: "GET",
          success: function(data){
            $data = $(data); 

            $('#admin').html($data).fadeIn();    
            }
        });
      });

      $(document).on('click','#summary', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/admin/summary',
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data){
              $data = $(data); 
              $('#admin').html($data).fadeIn();    
              }
          });
        });


    $(document).on('click','#admin_profile', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/admin/profile',
            type: "GET", 
            success: function(data){
              $data = $(data); 
              $('#admin').html($data).fadeIn();    
              }
          });
        });
          $(document).on('click','#add_student', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'/admin/add_student_form',
                type: "GET", 
                success: function(data){
                  $data = $(data);  produced
                  $('#admin').html($data).fadeIn();    
                  }
              });
            });
```

I tried to `redirect()->back->withInput('the fields');`, but it didn't work.
If there is better way to load the pages which holds the same page after reloading or form submission I would welcome that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ajax form posting.

I rewrote code to abstract ajax load.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //load summary by default
  loadPage('summary');

  //load on click menu item
  $(document).on('click','.menu-item', function(){
    loadPage($(this).attr('data-page'));
  });

  //send xcrf token in ajax header
  $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  });

  //submit form
  $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(){
    let form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'),
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        if(data.page){
            //load page returned in controller
            loadPage(data.page);
        }
      },
      error: function(data){
        if(data.responseJSON && data.responseJSON.errors){
            $.each(data.responseJSON.errors, function(key, value){

                //convert laravel dotted rules to jquery selectors

                key = key.replace('.', '[').replace(/\./g, '][');

                if(key.indexOf('[') !== -1){
                    key += ']';
                }

                //do something with errored elements
                form.find('*[name="' + key + '"]').addClass('error');
            });
        }
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
});

function loadPage(page){
  $.ajax({
    url:'/admin/' + page,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
      $data = $(data); 
      $('#admin').html($data).fadeIn();    
    }
  });
}
```

**HTML:**

Add to `<head>`:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Change sidebar menu:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item menu-item" data-page="summary">Dashboard</li>
    <li class="list-group-item menu-item" data-page="profile">Profile</li> 
    <li class="list-group-item" id="students">Students <i class="fas fa-angle-right ml-5"></i>
        <ul class="sidenav list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item menu-item" data-page="add_student_form">Add Student</li>
            <li class="list-group-item menu-item" data-page="viewall">View All </li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

**Controller method:**

Replace `return redirect()->back();` with `return ['page' => 'viewall'];`